Adding a delivery fee to woocommerce order based on text found in delivery address
We have a problem making deliveries to a specific building/address where drivers constantly face delays, so I wanted to enable a system that adds a surcharge based on text/keywords found within the delivery address. It has to be building-specific and it has to account for the various ways customers might type that address in. We have a lot of orders for this particular building so I was able to come up with common variants of that address.
I couldn't find a solution anywhere so had to come up with one. I think this will be helpful to people so I'm adding the snippet code here for anyone else to use.
Any suggestions for improving the code would be appreciated:
// Function to check if the address contains any of the specified keywords
function check_complex_delivery_surcharge( $address1, $address2 ) {
    $keywords = array( '6PSQ', '6 PSQ', '6 Parramatta Sq', '10 Darcy' ); // List of keywords to search for

    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword ) {
        if ( stripos( $address1, $keyword ) !== false || stripos( $address2, $keyword ) !== false ) { // Case-insensitive search
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Function to apply the complex delivery surcharge
function apply_complex_delivery_surcharge() {
    $address1 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(); // Get the customer's shipping address 1
    $address2 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2(); // Get the customer's shipping address 2
    
    if ( check_complex_delivery_surcharge( $address1, $address2 ) ) { // Check if either address matches any keywords
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Complex site delivery surcharge', 12, true, '' ); // Add a $12 surcharge that is taxable
        // To change the surcharge name and amount, modify 'Complex site delivery surcharge' and 12 respectively.
        // Example: WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Your Surcharge Name', 20, true, '' );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_complex_delivery_surcharge' ); // Hook to apply the surcharge during cart calculation

// Function to add a notification about the complex delivery surcharge
function add_complex_delivery_notification() {
    $address1 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(); // Get the customer's shipping address 1
    $address2 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2(); // Get the customer's shipping address 2
    
    if ( check_complex_delivery_surcharge( $address1, $address2 ) ) { // Check if either address matches any keywords
        echo '<tr class="complex-delivery-notice"><td colspan="2" style="color: #8B0000; font-size: x-small; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: left;">';
        echo 'Kindly note that a <strong>Complex Site Delivery Surcharge</strong> is now applicable for deliveries to <strong>6 Parramatta Square</strong> due to ongoing delivery delays in the building. This surcharge has been added to your cart (above).';
        echo '</td></tr>';
        // To change the notification message and styling, modify the content and styles inside the echo statements.
        // Example: echo 'Your custom message here.';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'add_complex_delivery_notification' ); // Hook to add the notification after the order total

// Function to remove duplicate notices
function remove_duplicate_notices() {
    wc_clear_notices(); // Clear any existing WooCommerce notices
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'remove_duplicate_notices', 1 ); // Hook to clear notices before the checkout form is displayed


If you think you have a solution to a common(?) problem to share, then please do so following the Q&A structure of this site - write a question that explains what problem needs solving first, and then post an actual answer to that question.

I’m voting to close this question because it is an answer not a question
